# Dynamic N columns bind to DetailsView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, detailsview

I have a stored procedure that return the data below:

```
HEIGHT    LENGTH    WEIGHT    WIDTH
0         0         0         0
```

The columns will be dynamic, can have up to N columns.

What I want to do is bind this result to Details View then let user key in the value.

But I have the error below when I bind to Details View:

DetailsView with id 'detailsViewProcessParameter' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate fields.  Ensure that your data source has content.

Here is the method that I use to return list of object then bind to details view:

```
public static List<object> GetProcessParameters(int formulaId)
{
    using (var db = new SurfaceTreatment.SurfaceTreatmentEntities())
    {
        var paramFormulaId = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "formulaId", Value = formulaId };
        var query = db.Database.SqlQuery<object>("exec usp_GetProcessParameters @formulaId", paramFormulaId).ToList();
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

I suspect that I should use "select new { PropertyName = Value, PropertyName = Value}" in my LINQ in order to get rid of the error.

But how do I select new when PropertyName(column name) are dynamic?

How do I use reflection to solve this?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are returning and thus binding a list of `objects` i.e. `List<object>` to DetailsView. I suspect that your object doesn't have any public property which DetailsView needs to Generate Rows and thus throws the error.

When using a list to bind to DetailsView ( or say a GridView ), the object in context, which is represented by some `Class`,  MUST have public properties . For example suppose we bind a List of User `List<User>` to DetailsView, then here the `User` class MUST have public properties which will form the Rows for DetailsView ( or Columns in GridView).

```
public class User
        {
           public string Name { get; set; }
           public int Age { get; set; }
           public string Mail { get; set; }
        }
```

With this basic concept, check to see what does your `query`  variable looks like and try to map this `query` variable to a `Class` with public properties.

Since in your case Columns are dynamic in nature, You must be first able to determine the total number of columns with there values, construct a corresponding DataTable at runtime and bind that data table to Detailsview.

Comment: But I cannot define a Class, because the data return from my stored procedure is dynamic, it can have up to N columns, and I wouldn't know the columns name(to become public property of Class), the column name in my example, it can be added into database by end user.

Comment: I understand that.  Atleast you need to check the total Columns/properties in your query variable, get the values for each column , dynamically generate a DataTable with the  required columns with respective values and Bind that DataTable to DetailsView.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `AutoGenerateRows` to `true` for the control, all the rows should generate automatically. I do not see any need to perform reflection.

Note that any property which is set for `DataKeyNames` will not be editable.